# How to deal with non-integers and Symfony's transchoice

Tags: symfony, pluralize

According to the documentation, the `$number` argument of `TranslatorInterface::transChoice` expects an integer. This is great for things like number of comments and such, but what about non-integers?

Say I want to pluralize an amount of years. My message table entry for English might look like this:

`{1} one year|]1,Inf[ %value% years`

But if you pass 1.4 to the `transChoice`, the result would be `one year` instead of `1.4 years`.

Is this simply a limitation of this system? Is there a workaround?